# WinRM - IIS Web App Management Azure Pipelines error

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to stop the app pool of a website by connecting to it remotely with TFS Step.
The step seems to be configured properly. The Deploy step works but the IIS Management doesn't

This is the Manage IISwebsite step:
[image]

In the log i'm getting an error with not so much feedback. I find nothing on the internet either

This is the log error `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Caught exception while executing main function: The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.`

Is there any way to do that, or by powershell script that i can run in a powershell task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter which was null was the adminPassword variable. No details were displayed, needed to debug the actual script of the TFS.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if so, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)